# Store players equipment

Tags: google-play-games

What is the best way to store players equipment. There is possible to store it in google play or I have to have my own database? I mean in my game will be some extra staff, that players could buy by virtual coins. Those virtual coins players could collect while playing game.

I need to store player coins and its equipment. Is this possible in google play?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *Saved Games* service of the *Google Play Games Services*
which is simple to implement and probably a faster way to retrieve data associated to a player in your game than using your *own* database. *Google Play Games Services* currently enforce size limits on binary data of 3 MB which is enough for saving a number of coins... Documentation : [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames).